# Images cut off on mass import

Tags: image, corruption, neto

I'm importing *a lot* of images, >50,000, to a Neto website and they're not importing correctly; at the bottom of some images, horizontal grey bars are rendered instead of the rest of the image.

Since it only affects the bottom and seemingly in sequence my best guess is it's something to do with timing; the server cuts the connection because it's timing out, then the CMS accepts and processes the image even though it's incomplete.

[Example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZfhC.jpg)

Let me know if your thoughts! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server was timing out, had to import in batches to fix.